Coulomb gas correlators on the sphere
I am trying to understand Appendix B.2 of Nakayama's notes (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0402009), wherein he derives the correlation functions of the following action (Coulomb gas) on the sphere:
$$ S = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int d^2\sigma \sqrt{g}g^{ab}\partial_a X \partial_b X + QRX .$$
The Appendix is an attempted solution to problem 6.2 in Polchinski's String Theory textbook.
However I am stumped by the fact that the $f(z, \overline{z})$'s do not actually cancel in Eq. B.43. If you notice carefully, the $f(z, \overline{z})$'s appear only in the first two terms in B.43, there is no term proportional to the background charge $Q$ that multiplies these zero-mode contributions. In my calculation, the $f$'s appear in the final correlator as
$$\exp{\left[4\left(\sum_i k_i\right)\sum_i i k_if(z_i, \overline{z}_i)\right]}.$$
Of course, when Joe does this calculation in his book for $Q = 0$, the above term is 1 due to charge neutrality. But in the presenece of the background charge, the overall constant multiplying the $f$'s should be something like $\left(\sum k_i - 2iQ\right)$, however with Nakayama's notation I am unable to see where this might come from.
What am I missing?
